# Predict the values of the unknown numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction, missing-data

I have a training data set which is composed of 14 integer numbers separated by a blank. Each number is a 1 (one) or a 2 (two). The i-th number can be understood as the presence of the corresponding feature. One means false and two means true. The training data set looks like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

And the test data set contains 10000 lines, representing samples where some of the data are missing. This is represented by zeros, one per line. The testing data look like this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1
0 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 1 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 0 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I am very new to machine learning, I would like to know a way to predict those missing values. I know in scikit learn there is a class call `Imputer` which allows you to find those missing values. But it does not use any train data. So it would be great, if someone can give me some points to tackle this problem

Comment: This is way too broad and not really on-topic for StackOverflow. You should try Cross Validated. There are many different ways to go about imputation.

Comment: One approach could be to create 14 classifiers with your training data. Each one would predict the presence or absence in feature 1 till 14 given the other features. The input to your classifiers could be (apart from the raw value of each row), the sum of 1s and 2s, the difference between 1s and 2s etc.